# NSNumber : numberWith n initWith

Tags: objective-c

Is there any difference

[NSNumber numberWithInteger:  ]

[NSNumber initWithIneger:   ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number returned by `+numberWithInteger:` is autoreleased; the one returned by `-initWithInteger:` isn't. (Also, you need to `+alloc` NSNumber before sending `-initWithInteger:`, while you don't do that with `+numberWithInteger:`'.)

```
NSNumber *foo = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:7]; // you must release foo when done
NSNumber *bar = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:7];       // bar is autoreleased
```

Answer (score -2):

initWithIneger: starts with "init", so you need to release the object this method returns.

numberWithInteger: does not start with "init" or "new" or "alloc", so the object this returns is autoreleased. You don't need to release it. If you wanna keep it for later use, you need to retain it.

Comment: Check [the rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html): "init" isn't one of the key words that tells you that the retain count is increasing: "alloc", "new", "copy", and "retain" are what you're thinking of.